# iOS How to update location of assets in photo editing extension?

Tags: ios, location, photosframework

I'm working with *Photo Editing Extension* and I'm faced with a problem, how can I update the location of photo via Photos Framework? We have the method *finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler*:

```
func finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((PHContentEditingOutput!) -> Void)!) {
    // Update UI to reflect that editing has finished and output is being rendered.

    // Render and provide output on a background queue.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(CLong(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT), 0)) {
        // Create editing output from the editing input.
        let output = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: self.input)

        // Provide new adjustments and render output to given location.
        // output.adjustmentData = <#new adjustment data#>
        // let renderedJPEGData = <#output JPEG#>
        // renderedJPEGData.writeToURL(output.renderedContentURL, atomically: true)

        // Call completion handler to commit edit to Photos.
        completionHandler?(output)

        // Clean up temporary files, etc.
    }
}
```

And we have *PHContentEditingOutput*, are there ways to change location? How to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Comment from @Niklas) I'm facing the a similar problem. However, I can update the (GPS) location of the photo, but Photos is not updated. If I export the photo and inspect the file, the location is there, and if I import it again in photos the new photo has a location, but never the old one. Did you find a solution to your problem?